# NSFetchedResultsController.sortDescriptor by KeyPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

How can I set my `fetchedResultsController.sortDescriptors` to contain a sortdescriptor that uses a keypath, for instance, such as `@"foo.name"`?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite `NSSortDescriptor`'s use of the name “key”, it actually takes a key path, as described in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSSortDescriptor/sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:selector:). So, just create an `NSSortDescriptor` with your key path as the “key”, and use that.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I tried that, but it failed, but the document sais so indeed so I must have got something else wrong. Thanks for the help :-)